# Convoluted explanation of different types of Raman scattering

Tags: raman

I am currently studying the textbook *Surface-Enhanced Raman Spectroscopy -- Bioanalytical, Biomolecular and Medical Applications* by Marek Procházka.

I just read this passage from chapter 2:

> Rayleigh scattering arises when the energy of the molecular system both before and after the scattering process is the same ($\hbar \omega_{\text{s}} = \hbar \omega_{\text{inc}}$). The occurrence of inelastic light scattering can be explained by classical theory in terms of a modulation of the incident radiation $E_{\text{loc}}(\omega_{\text{inc}})$ by a vibrating molecule with frequency $\omega_{\text{vib}}$. Raman frequency can be smaller $\omega_{\text{inc}} - \omega_{\text{vib}}$ or larger $\omega_{\text{inc}} + \omega_{\text{vib}}$ than that of the incoming photon $\omega_{\text{inc}}$. When the incident radiation is shifted to a lower frequency (lower energy), the scattered light is called Stokes shift. In this type of scattering the energy is transferred to the vibrational mode of the molecule which ends up in a higher vibrational energy state. Similarly, when the incident radiation is shifted to a higher frequency (higher energy), the scattered light is called anti-Stokes shift. In this type of scattering the energy is transferred from a vibrationally excited molecule, which ends up in a lower vibrational state after the scattering event. The scattering process when an intermediate “virtual state” does not correspond to a real energy level of the molecule is called normal Raman scattering (NRS)$^2$.
>
> $^2$ The term “RS” is often used for RS under nonresonant (normal) conditions, term “normal RS” (or sometimes classical RS) is used to distinguish it from resonance RS under resonant conditions. Note that there is also the case of preresonant RS.

In particular, it is this part that I don't understand:

> $^2$ The term “RS” is often used for RS under nonresonant (normal) conditions, term “normal RS” (or sometimes classical RS) is used to distinguish it from resonance RS under resonant conditions. Note that there is also the case of preresonant RS.

This is written so convolutedly that I do not at all understand what it is saying, nor can I distinguish between the different types of RS (Raman scattering) that it is referring to. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: The author does not seem to have a good command of the English language. There are obvious semantic errors in the more simple parts (check the upside-down logic of the first senctence), and he fails as soon as it gets complicated. I would return that book.

Comment: The only different is that the exciting light is close to an electronic transition in resonance Raman Scattering . Look at Wikipedia for Resonant Raman Scattering. This explains this clearly compared to 'ordinary' or conventional Raman Scattering.

Comment: @Karl Hmm, the first sentence seems to make sense to me; what, specifically, are you referring to? The earlier parts of the textbook seem to be fine; it's just this part that I thought was confusing. Do you happen to have experience a different surface-enhanced Raman spectroscopy textbook that you think is superior?

Comment: @porphyrin Can you please be more specific in what parts of the statement you are referring to? Like I said, it's very convoluted, so I'm having difficulty mapping what you said onto it.

Comment: I would ignore the book and look at the Wikipedia pages then at another textbook or review article.

Comment: @porphyrin So you also think that I should return this textbook?

Comment: yes, certainly do that. There is bound to be another that will clarify things for you or look in the literature for a review article.

Comment: @porphyrin Ok, will do. Thank you to you both for the advice.

Comment: The word "arises" is simply wrong. If you have an "afterwards" state, then the scattering has already occured. If the two states have the same energy, you *call* it a Rayleigh scatering. You can say no problem, it´s clear what he means, but as soon as you want to expain sth. beyond the obvious, sloppy semantics are fatal.